# Remove Unfinished String with Ellipsis using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove the String with *Ellipsis* from **unfinished** **sentences/words** not any sentence with Ellipsis:

```
1. String ... String
2. String String Str...
3. String string String ...
4. String Strin... String
5. String String ... Stri==...
```

**Output**:

```
1. String ... String
3. String string String ...
```

My first thought was trying to iterate each sentence, but I think **regex** would be better(wayy better).

Is that possible with **regex**?
if so How come? I tried few **regex** unsuccessfully.

Any help will be appreciate.

**ps**: I can't post the actual strings (company policies), that's why I posted these dummy examples.

**Edit:**

I've tried regex like:

```
    /(\.*)\.\.\./mgi (I'm not an expert)
```

but will fail in some cases...

I will retrieve each sentence in an array of String, not a huge and messy String.

Well basically anything with unfinished word or sentence I need to discart. (anything with a word or a single character infront of a *Ellipsis*)

Comment: Can you Please post your regex as well. https://regex101.com/ This is a wonderful tool to play with regex and understand that your regex just works fine

Comment: a) If you can't post an exact example, make one that is as close as possible. I doubt your real case involves a single word repeating. If you have "To boldly go...", write "In recent times...", for example. Don't make examples that have less information than the real data. b) Do you have an array of strings that are one sentence each? Or a giant string with unseparated sentences? Or are you evaluating each sentence one by one?  (This goes back to "have data as real as possible") c) What exactly have you tried? d) Is "String..." a valid sentence? If yes, how do you know?

Comment: What's the rule for "any sentence with Elipsis"? In your output it shows that they're the ones in between spaces and another space/or end of line.

Comment: @Amadan I updated the question

Comment: i updated my answer to cover the 5th sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume an invalid sentence always have a word with `...` immediately after.

In the regex below, you could put anything that actually separate your words. For now, I put `.` and  (space character).

```
var str = `1. String ... String
2. String String Str...
3. String string String ...
4. String Strin... String
5. String String ... Stri==...`;

var cleaned = str.split('\n').filter(function (line) {
    return !line.match(/[^\. ]+\.{3}/);
}).join('\n');

console.log(cleaned);
/*
prints

1. String ... String
3. String string String ...
*/
```

Comment: your welcome. I dont know why i got a downvote in the meantime!

Comment: if that answers your question, consider marking it as the answer for future visitors.

Comment: @Amir It was because some high rep user (forgot their name). Stated this doesn't work because you need to check at the end of the string (*they didn't read the question properly*). I'm assuming that's where it came from.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Thanks, I was wondering what did I wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, you are basically looking for `[any character 1 or more times][...]`, which would be in regexp:

```
\w+\.{3}
```

This is assuming that Ellipsis is always 3 dots, if it's not you can do `\.+` instead. Use that to find the sentences you want to remove, then keep the other items.